# Writing and reading core data at the same time causing a UI freeze until writing is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When my app is launched it syncs a set of entities with the server.
During this sync, it updates the entities in core data and saves it.
If you open the app (sync starts) and then I press on my tabbar button that should show the tableView (with NSFetchedResultsController) it freezes for a few moments.

I really don't know where to look for the issue.

Update with some extra info:

I'm using a master(parent) context that is used for the fetch for the NSFetchedResultsController and chil context(s) that are used in the sync class to download and save the changes.

When all changes are done, I save the child context and the parent(master) context one after the other. (I assume that this is needed.).

Comment: Are you performing this on the main thread? If yes dispatch it to a background thread so the UI does not freeze.

Comment: The syncing with the server is happening on a background thread. I'm doing the fetch like it is showed here in viewDidLoad on the main thread: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999 I read in different posts/sources that the fetch operation should be performed on the main thread.

Comment: Perform the fetch in a background queue, perform only the UI updates in the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming from your statements that your Main Context is being created like this

```
let mainContext = NSManagedObjectContext.init(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = CoreDatStack.sharedStack.persistentStoreCoordinator
```

You have created Child Context as Below

```
let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext.init(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    childContext.parent = mainContext
```

Reason for freezes : Your save operation of mainContext executes on MainThread(as writing to disk(persistent store) is slow process) , Hence block the main thread until save operation is done.

Solution: Make the context who links with PersistentStoreCoordinator on privateQueue so that saving will not execute on Main Queue.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad add something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);

// execute a task on that queue asynchronously
dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{

    //fetch code here


    // some code on a main thread (delegates, notifications, UI updates...)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     //UI updates here



    });
});
```